When a new Object is added to the Org, Bot User should get automatic Read Access
I'm thinking to build an Integration Bot User with Standard Profile and 1 permission set that has Read Access (and no Edit Access) on all Objects in the Org. They also need Read-only to all records.
I have the requirement, then when a new Object is added to the Org, the same Permission Set be given Read Access automatically.
Is there a best practices for this requirement, or is Flow the best option here?
Also, if you disagree with this overall architecture, please provide a better one. I've read a lot of documentation/articles already, including on the API Integration License and Profile.

any new Object - including new standard objects? what about new objects added by managed packages?  Why not just give the BOT user View All Data permission that allows all objects to be read.

I found it! This just might fulfill the requirement

System Permission: VIEW All Data - applies to every object; however, will not give FLS on the fields

Thanks @cropredy I added the Sys Permission to my Permission Set, and I gave the user a Minimal Profile where all objects have "No Access". When I login as the User... Account, Lead and others objects are not available in the Waifer. What am I missing here?
I thought Permission Set extends Profile, so if Account has No Access at the Profile level, but it has Read at the Permission Set level, then you can read all Accounts.

I'm not sure what implications are involved with no Field Level Security, as you mentioned above. Please let me know if there is something I need to do about it.

ViewAllData enables R access to any object, regardless of ownership or sharing rules. However, the assigned user won't be able to see any fields unless FLS is granted to a profile or permission set assigned to that user.

Thanks @cropredy. This has been helpful! Thank you. I now have an Integration User with Permission Set (with System: View All Data) and Profile where all Objects show No Access.
I'll give this to my AWS pro to use to make API calls to Salesforce, so he can bring all data into a data lake. In this case, it seems FLS, Tab availability and a lot of other things are fine deactivated, since he's just calling the API. It seems that View All Data is all he needs to get all data from SF to the data lake. Do you agree or disagree?

given that you have credentials for this integration user; log in to SFDC using Postman or Workbench and make a REST call to the SFDC API using SOQL and see if you can see any field values for custom  or standard object, non-mandatory fields (like Account.Website) and see if the integration user can see the value of that field. Without FLS R on the field, the answer should be NO

Thanks @cropredy for pointing me to Veiw All Data under System Permissions (on Profile or Permission Set). This automatically adds Read and View All to all objects, including newly added objects.
It does not change FLS or Tab visibility or other things you may need to view the Objects in the view.
In another question, System Permission set to View All Records. Why can't User view Account and other standard objects?
I asked more about API access for this Bot User, and got this from @sfdcfox:
The new integration model replaces the older API Only System Integrations model (see Client Credentials Flow)
Since I have 400+ objects to update for FLS and Tab visibility, I'll create or find a Batch Job script to run for that.
